# How to conditionally construct a tensor from two other tensors in PyTorch on the GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch

An example:

```py
import torch

pred = torch.tensor([1,2,1,0,0], device='cuda:0')
correct = torch.tensor([1,0,1,1,0], device='cuda:0')
assigned = torch.tensor([1,2,2,1,0], device='cuda:0')
```

I want `result = tensor([1,2,1,1,0], device='cuda:0')`.

1. Basically, when `pred` is same as `correct` then `correct` else `assigned`.
2. Moreover, I want to exclude this computation from the gradient computation.

Is there a way to do this without iterating over the tensors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.where.html#torch.where) does exactly what you're looking for:

```py
import torch

pred = torch.tensor([1,2,1,0,0], device='cuda:0')
correct = torch.tensor([1,0,1,1,0], device='cuda:0')
assigned = torch.tensor([1,2,2,1,0], device='cuda:0')

result = torch.where(pred == correct, correct, assigned)

print(result)
# >>> tensor([1, 2, 1, 1, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

Since none of these tensors have `requires_grad=True`, nothing needs to be done to avoid gradient computation. Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```py
import torch

pred = torch.tensor([1.,2.,1.,0.,0.], device='cuda:0')
correct = torch.tensor([1.,0.,1.,1.,0.], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
assigned = torch.tensor([1.,2.,2.,1.,0.], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)

with torch.no_grad():
    result = torch.where(pred == correct, correct, assigned)

print(result)
# >>> tensor([1, 2, 1, 1, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

If you do not use `torch.no_grad()`, you'll have:

```py
result = torch.where(pred == correct, correct, assigned)
print(result)
# >>> tensor([1., 2., 1., 1., 0.], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SWhereBackward>)
```

which, then, can be detached from the computational graph by using:

```py
result = result.detach()
print(result)
# >>> tensor([1., 2., 1., 1., 0.], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. 
I want to clarify one more thing:

For my use case, I need to dynamically compute the gold labels (that will be passed to the cross-entropy loss function) based on the prediction and the correct labels 

'''
def loss_function(self, logits, correct_labels, assigned_labels):
    predicted_label = logits.max(dim=1)[1]
    # Compute gold_labels using predicted_label, correct_label, assigned_label
    return torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(logits, gold_labels)
'''
So, do I need to enclose the computation part within torch.no_grad() block?

Comment: @NRJ_Varshney it seems that you wouldn't want gradients to flow through your "gold labels"